# htaccess redirect temporary old directory to current

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I changed one subdirectory name from website/A_tmp/para_1/para_2 to website/A/para_1/para_2 (used htaccess rewrite the url) after A_tmp in production for a few weeks. Now, after 1 year, google is still reporting 404 on A_tmp errors.

How to fix that problem? If htaccess can do the trick, how to write that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 301 redirection in htaccess, so google will know that this resource is moved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 301 rule like this. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^A_tmp(/.*|)$ A/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```